# How to Determine the Minimum Value of a Continuous Variable for Predicting Categorical variable using Logistic Regression?

Tags: machine-learning, python, statistics, logistic-regression

I am using logistic regression to predict df['MortSubiteCardiaque'], which contains 0 and 1, based on my continuous variable df['NTProBNP']. I would like to determine the threshold for df['NTProBNP'], specifically the minimum value of df['NTProBNP'] that predicts 1. How can I do that?

```
  df['constante'] = 1

  X = df[['constante', 'NTProBNP']]
 y = df['MortSubiteCardiaque']

 model = sm.Logit(y, X)
 result = model.fit()

 y_probs = result.predict(X)

 fpr, tpr, thresholds = roc_curve(y, y_probs)

 roc_auc = auc(fpr, tpr)
 # optimal cut-off point 
 optimal_idx = np.argmax(tpr - fpr)
optimal_threshold = thresholds[optimal_idx]


# i had 2361 with this line 
df['NTProBNP'][y_probs >= optimal_threshold].min()
```

Comment: Is the scale of `NTProBNP` such that higher values correspond more to `MortSubiteCardiaque` = 1?

Comment: #@m13op22  yes,
mean      5116.904762
std       6759.119454
min         15.000000
25%        737.250000
50%       2463.500000
75%       5514.250000
max      25000.000000

I think I can find the solution by inverting the logistic function, setting it equal to the optimal threshold. This solution seems logical to me, but I can't find a reference.